# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement-new to this and totally lost

Tags: syntax-error, ms-access-2010, insert-into

I am trying to allow a simple form containing drop down lists that can also allow additions to the list without going through the design view etc.

The following continues to come up on my screen and prohibits me from accomplish...i alway end up with the following error:

> Run-time error '3134':
>   Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

This is the code with which it takes issue:

```
Private Sub Ctl1_Auditory_Perception_NotInList (NewData As String, Response As Integer)
    Dim strSql     As String
    If MsgBox(NewData & " not in list, add?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
        strSql = "insert into tblEOY assessments(1 Auditory Perception) values(" & NewData & ")"
        CurrentDb.Execute strSql
        Response = acDataErrAdded
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `NewData` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT query is definitely wrong, although it's hard to correct without seeing the table structure and knowing what exactly you want to do.

Here's the proper format for an insert though:

```
INSERT INTO tablename ( fieldname1, fieldname2 )
VALUES ( value1, value2 )
```

For more specific help, you'll need to show us your table structure, the value of your NewData variable, and what data you want inserted.